# Do function after jQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am currently trying to make my Ajax to post some informations from a HTML form, into a PHP form.

Well, now I have made difference codes which should be printed out at the "ajax.comment.php" page, telling what happened.

Like if it went successfully or not.

I now want to make my ajax, check what the printed html was.
And then handle on that.. Like if (Printed HTML == "1") {Then do something}.

How can I do that?

My following javascript is:

```
var name = document.comment.name.value;
var email = document.comment.email.value;
var website = document.comment.website.value;
var message = document.comment.message.value;
var id = document.comment.id.value;
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax.addcomment.php",
      data: "name="+name+"&email="+email+"&website="+website+"&message="+message+"&id="+id,
      beforeSend: function() {
        // Action before sending data
      },
      success: function(returned_html) {
        // Action after sending data, where the returned_html var is the returned html text by the php
      }
  });
```

Comment: Isn't `returned_html` you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your `success` function, try this:

```
success: function(returned_html) {
    var the_result = $.trim(returned_html);
    if(the_result == '1')
    {
        // Do whatever you wanted here.
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something else here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to mention the usual about javascript - you may want to do the_result === '1' to ensure that the result is both 1 and a string -usually it is good to be explicit early just in case you are going to do something with the_result later and it doesn't behave how you expect

Comment: Actually, running `$.trim()` will **always** return a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done. just do what you want in the `success` callback which you already implemented.

btw, i've serialized your form so that you don't need to take values individually (unless you want to do something with them).

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax.addcomment.php",
      data: $('#comment').serialize(),
      success: function(returned_html) {
        if(returned_html == 1){ 
           //lets do our thing
        } else {
           //lets do other things
      }
  });
```

Comment: An ajax call, or any http post/get for that matter, will never return an integer ;)  See the answer 3 minutes before yours for the correct format.  Good call on `serialize()` though.

Comment: it's not identity check! should work :s. but yes, trimming probably better.